# Why my "gets" is not taking user input but rather printing the first line in the comment?

Tags: ruby

I started to learn ruby. I have the following code(using windows):

```
=begin file_new = File.new("temp.txt","w")

file_new.puts............................
.........................................

=end 

puts "What is your name?"


name = gets

puts "Hello"+name+"! How are you?"
```

Without letting me entering my input, it's printing the following:

```
What is your name?
Hello=begin file_new = File.new("temp.txt","w")
! How are you?
```

Why it's reading my commented previous code segment instead of taking user input?

**Edit**

So I deleted the multi line comments and getting the following:

```
What is your name?
Helloputs "What is your name?"! How are you?
```

**Edit2:**
This is the output after putting `p ARGV` to the beginning of the script.

```
C:\RubyWorkSpace>ruby ruby.rb
["ruby.rb"]
What is your name?
Hellop ARGV! How are you?
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. How are you executing the code?

Comment: So what should I do on my machine?Does it have something to do with my installation of Ruby?

Comment: I'm using windows. All I'm doing is ruby ruby.rb , the way it should be executed.The name of my file is ruby.rb

Comment: I restated everything but still the same.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Unix. I don't think it will be so much of a difference. I'm running without any extra options too. just pure `ruby`

Comment: Well, you could remove the multi-line comment, change `name = gets` to `name = gets.chomp`, and see if the code runs correctly.  Beyond that, you are suggesting that there's a bug in ruby's multi-line comments syntax.  More likely, there's "something else" that's causing this behavior.

Comment: @orde I'm still getting weird output.Please see my edited question.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running `ruby ruby.rb` and not `ruby ruby.rb ruby.rb` or something similar? Can you add `p ARGV` to the beginning of your script and post its output?

Comment: @sepp2k I am sorry but what is p ARGV?

Comment: It prints the command line arguments that have been passed to your script. If you run it as `ruby ruby.rb`, `ARGV` should be empty. I just want to verify that.

Comment: @sepp2k I posted.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is invoked with command line arguments, `gets` will interpret them as a list of file and read from those files rather than from stdin. This is meant as a shortcut to create scripts acting like `grep` and similar command line tools, which will process the given files or stdin if no files were given (making it easy to pipe input to them in shell scripts). If you always want to read from stdin, you should use `STDIN.gets`.

In your case you don't seem to be invoking your script with any command line arguments, but you actually are: due to the way Windows handles file extensions in the command line, you can just type in `foo` to start a ruby script named `foo.rb`. Your script is named `ruby.rb` and when you type in `ruby`, Windows actually executes your script `ruby.rb` rather than `ruby.exe`, the Ruby interpreter. So `ruby ruby.rb` actually invokes your script `ruby.rb` with the argument `ruby.rb`. To invoke your script without arguments, just type `ruby`, `ruby.rb` or, if you want to invoke the interpreter explicitly `ruby.exe ruby.rb`. You can also rename your script to something other than `ruby` to avoid this problem.

Comment: @SittingBull Please also see my edit regarding why this happens.